# Making a Login script work with JQuery and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have a form that I'm trying to submit via AJAX:
This is how I set it up to test my php script that handles the login.

```
<form  class="login_form" method="post" action="login_ajax.php">
  Email: <input name="email" type="text" /> <br />
  Password: <input name="pass" type="password" /> <br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This seems to work; correct credentials give a good return, json object with a "success" attribute, incorrect credentials gives a "failed" json object.

But then when I try to set up the script, nothing works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".login_form").submit(function () {
       try {
        $.post("login_ajax.php", {'email':this.email.value, 'pass':this.pass.value},
          function (data) {
              alert("Back from AJAX");
          }, 'json');
       alert("Sent to AJAX");
       }
       catch(e) {
        alert(e);
       }
       return false;
   });
});
```

I'm not getting any exceptions, but nor am I getting the "BACK" alert.  I just get the "Sent to AJAX" and then nothing.  Is there something I misunderstand about the callback function passed to jQuery.post, that it would never be called?

EDIT:  I replaced my .post line with the one below, and it worked correctly, the success function gets called and I've got the data that I want.  I was under the impression that these were essentially equivalent.

```
$.ajax("login_ajax.php", 
     {'type':'POST', 
      'data':{'email':this.email.value, 'pass':this.pass.value},
      'error':function(thingy,status,em) {alert("ERROR: "+em);}, 
      'success':function(data, status) {alert(JSON.stringify(data));} 
      });
```

Comment: its working make sure you have loaded `jQuery`,

Comment: I wouldn't be getting the "Sent to AJAX" alert if I hadn't loaded JQuery.

Comment: is your data sent to login_ajax.php?

Comment: Is there a way I can check that?  The Network tab says Status 200, but I'm not getting any feedback from the AJAX call, since that's my problem.

Comment: How do you return 'succes' or 'failed' in login_ajax.php? its better if you provide the php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your network tab in your browser console and see if you're posting anything and check out the response from the server, post it here.

you may also want to use the full $.ajax() method and see if that works for you, you have access to the "error" callback whereas with the shortcut $.post you do not.

**UPDATE:** Try this code and tell us what you get:

```
$.ajax({
        "url" : "login_ajax.php",
        "data" : {'email':this.email.value, 'pass':this.pass.value},
        "type" : "POST",
        "dataType" : "json",
        "success" : function(data){
            alert("Back from successful ajax request");
        },
        "error" : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("Oops, there was an problem: " + errorThrown);
        }

    });
```

Comment: It says Status is 200 OK, even though it never ran the callback.

Comment: I did this (well, my version, slightly more correct) , see the edit to the question.

Comment: Oops you're right, I forgot the "type" option.. fixed. Glad this helped you

Comment: Yeah.  I still would like to figure out what was wrong with the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working you can see demo.

#### [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JLkyv/2/)

in DEMO you can not see back alert because `login_ajax.php` file is not present.

if its still not working check jQuery loaded on not because in fiddle jQuery will be added automatically.

If still now work use `e.preventDefault();`

**Example**

```
$(".login_form").submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: The demo does exactly what my code does, it alerts "Sent to AJAX", but never alerts "Back from AJAX", which is the problem.

Comment: @Retsam yes i know its because in demo there is no `login_ajax.php` file preset..make sure your code can reach to that file..

Comment: Right; making a demo that has the exact same symptoms as my code isn't helpful.  
I do have access to that file because the first version without any javascript (just the form) works correctly.

Comment: @Retsam i know its not helpful but atleast that clear the point that what could be the error....now can i see login_ajax.php code.??

Comment: In your network tab, the post to login_ajax.php is returning 200? Are you sure?